# Update document.cookie updates all cookies onclick and not just one

Tags: javascript, templates, cookies, foreach, setcookie

I'm creating a chrome extension, where within my application, I want to be able to update Google Optimize cookies on the click of a button.

So far, I'm utilising items of data from `window.gaData["UA-MY-ID"].experiments`, which looks like this:

```
window.gaData["UA-MY-ID"].experiments = {
  2kgkOYLpTiWA36wf-_Ir7Q: "0"
  JVEtsVqdQm-lZPxXQUzdQw: "0"
}
```

The same range of numbers/letters represents, the variant ID, as well as the cookie ID.
The associated cookies looks like this and the cookies in particular I need to manipulate, begin with **_gaexp**:

`window.document.cookie "_ga=GA1.3.1001449090.1593816402; _gaexp=GAX1.3.2kgkOYLpTiWA36wf-_Ir7Q.18539.0!JVEtsVqdQm-lZPxXQUzdQw.18539.0; _gid=GA1.3.246809878.1594039125; _ga=GA1.3.1001449090.1593816402"`

**Breaking this down, I need to update the following, (but only when I click on the corresponding button/ID):**

_gaexp=GAX1.3.2kgkOYLpTiWA36wf-_Ir7Q.18539.**0**!JVEtsVqdQm-lZPxXQUzdQw.18539.**0**;

**To:**

_gaexp=GAX1.3.2kgkOYLpTiWA36wf-_Ir7Q.18539.**1**!JVEtsVqdQm-lZPxXQUzdQw.18539.**1**;

**I'm then looping through this data and displaying them in the DOM.  Here's an example:**

```
<div class="variant-0-container" id="variant-0-container">
      <div class="CRO-variant-result">
        <p>Experiment ID: 2kgkOYLpTiWA36wf-_Ir7Q </p>
        <p>Variant Active: 0</p>
        <button onclick="buttonClick(&quot;2kgkOYLpTiWA36wf-_Ir7Q&quot;)" id="2kgkOYLpTiWA36wf-_Ir7Q">Switch variant</button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="CRO-variant-result">
        <p>Experiment ID: JVEtsVqdQm-lZPxXQUzdQw </p>
        <p>Variant Active: 0</p>
        <button onclick="buttonClick(&quot;JVEtsVqdQm-lZPxXQUzdQw&quot;)" id="JVEtsVqdQm-lZPxXQUzdQw">Switch variant</button>
      </div>
      </div>
```

**What I want to do:**

When I click on any button, I want to update my cookies and change my variant from `0` to `1`.  But only when the specific button is clicked.

**What my problem is:**

When I click on a button, all the cookies update to `1` at the same time.  But I only want the specific button I've clicked, to update the specific cookie.

**So the end result should be something like this, if I only click the corresponding button, with the corresponding ID:**

gaexp=GAX1.3.2kgkOYLpTiWA36wf-_Ir7Q.18539.**1**!JVEtsVqdQm-lZPxXQUzdQw.18539.**0**

**Here's my specific JavaScript code.... What am I doing wrong?**

- I'm looping through my `window.gadata` object.
- Appending the correct variant ID/cookie ID to the button.
- And then I have an onClick function `buttonClick`,
- Which is using a template literal, to pass the `${key}` value clicked, into the

  `window.document.cookie` declaration to delete and add/overwrite the cookie.

  ```
  Object.keys(window.gaData["UA-MY-ID"].experiments).forEach(function(key, index){
    var value = window.gaData["UA-MY-ID"].experiments[key];

    if (value === "0") {
      console.log('key, value: ', key, value, index);

      result += `
      <div class="CRO-variant-result">
        <p>Experiment ID: ${key} </p>
        <p>Variant Active: ${value}</p>
        <button onclick="buttonClick(${JSON.stringify(key).split('"').join("&quot;")})" id=${key}>Switch variant</button>
      </div>
      `
      document.getElementById('variant-0-container').innerHTML = result;
    }
  });

  buttonClick = (key) => {
    console.log('clicked!')
    console.log('key', key);
    // Delete
    window.document.cookie = `_gaexp=GAX1.3.${key}.18539.0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2021 20:47:11 UTC; path=/; domain=.MYWEBSITE.co.uk`
    // Add
    window.document.cookie = `_gaexp=GAX1.3.${key}.18539.1; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/; domain=.MYWEBSITE.co.uk`
    window.location.reload();
  }
  ```

But this seems to update all the cookies. And not the one, which has been specifically targeted, via onClick/`${key}`.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

All experiments are stored in a single cookie, with a key of `_gaexp`, and they are concatenated in the value, separated by `!`:

```
//            |        experiment A          |        experiment B          |
"_gaexp=GAX1.3.2kgkOYLpTiWA36wf-_Ir7Q.18539.1!JVEtsVqdQm-lZPxXQUzdQw.18539.0"
```

Right now, you are overwriting the entire value with a single experiment, and losing the others. Maybe you could build that full string again, using `window.gaData` as a source?

From my understanding, this should work:

```
const container   = document.getElementById('variant-0-container'),
      experiments = window.gaData["UA-MY-ID"].experiments;

container.innerHTML = Object.entries(experiments)
  .filter(([key, value]) => value == 0)
  .map(([key, value]) => `
    <div class="CRO-variant-result">
      <p>Experiment ID: ${key} </p>
      <p>Variant Active: ${value}</p>
      <button class="switch-btn" id="${key}">Switch variant</button>
    </div>
  `)
  .join('');

container.querySelectorAll('.switch-btn').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => buttonClick(btn.id));
});

function buttonClick(key) {
  const str = Object.entries(experiments)
    .map(([k, v]) => `${k}.18539.${k === key ? 1 : v}`)
    .join('!');

  const now = new Date();
  const expireTime = now.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // 1 year?
  now.setTime(expireTime);

  window.document.cookie = `_gaexp=GAX1.3.${str}; expires=${now.toGMTString()}; path=/; domain=.MYWEBSITE.co.uk`
  window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @blex! I'm going to give this solution a go today and will come back to you. But yes, I realised that originally, I'm not actually updating the whole cookie. And I need to split up and manipulate the cookie, before putting the values back together and then overwriting it.  Thank you! Will report back later today!